# tElement vs iElement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am confused with reference to an element in directive compile and link functions.

If no ng-if or ng-switch has been used with directive this two functions has the same reference element. However, if I use ng-if/ng-switch they are not the same reference anymore even if they do refer to the same object.

Moreover, the same happens to all other references to elements which I would save during compilation (with ng-if/.. they are useless).
I manage to solve the issue by moving all references to link stage, but I would like to understand the reasoning behind.

I had made small demo:

```js
angular.module('demo', [])
  .directive('direc', function() {
    return {
      compile: function(tElement) {
        return function($scope, iElement) {
          console.dir(tElement, iElement);
          iElement.text((tElement === iElement) ? 'true' : 'false');
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo">
  Without ng-if : compile(Element) === link(Element) : <direc></direc>
  </br>
  With ng-if : compile(Element) === link(Element) :  <direc ng-if='true'></direc>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When we look at official [angularjs doc.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

> iElement - instance element - The element where the directive is to be
>   used.
>
> tElement - template element - The element where the directive has been
>   declared.

and, when you use `ng-if or ng-switch` both creates [`new child scope.`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), and new element gets created. So `tElement` and `iElement` are **not same**.,

So in new scope case when you do debugging in broswer console you could see the `tElement` in case of `ng-if` bound to document only, whereas `iElement` is bound to current instance element.*(check in ELement tab of chrome)*

So you can use `ng-show` which doesn't create new child scope to achieve same.

See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t2jcgmfm/), and observe the difference in `scope and instance binding.`